# iOS simulator and gps

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, simulator

How do I simulate GPS movement on iOS simulator? I am developing an app that uses gps an I need to test it while the user location is changing.. How can I do that? thank you in advance..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the `Features > Location` menu of the iOS Simulator, check the `Location` menu:

<sup>**Note**: The screenshot below is outdated, however the path above has been updated to reflect the proper menu location for this option.</sup>

[image: Debug menu of iOS Simulator]

It provides you with several options pertaining to changing the location of the simulated device.

Answer (score 10):

For those that are getting here in 2020, things have changed a little bit,
You'll find the options to modify location settings under Features[image]