# User Current Location

Tags: ios

I want to receive in coordinates the users current location and I entered this code:

```
-(void)update{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

On iOS Simulator, this code is crashing and on my device it is not or sometimes its crashes the whole app.... can you help me on what is going on?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is failing" on the simulator? And what do you mean by "fails the whole app"? Can you describe the crashes/errors you're getting?

Comment: The simulator is not capable of providing the whole gps expereince. It has just basic capability as of providing the location. E.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641817/ios-simulator-and-gps

Comment: Please be a little clearer about what isn't working. What are you expecting and what is not happening?

Comment: This is not an Xcode question...

Comment: Try to elaborare your question with understandable .....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like maybe you're not implementing the [CLLocationManagerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) methods.

In particular `-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` (from iOS 6) or `-locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` in previous iOS versions.

Maybe (again your question is so vague) you only want to show the blue dot on a map view. In which case you don't need to deal with the Core Location Manager. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9928321/662605) for more information.

Comment: the term failing means crashes. I need the CLLLocationmanager for a unique feature I designed and yes it is Xcode. Thks for your help

Comment: So tell me what your feature technically needs to achieve. No one can help you without some more technical information.

Answer (score 1):

1st of all You can't get your current Location in the Simulator . and try with this code for getting the co-ordinates of current Location.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center=coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=10.015;
    span.longitudeDelta=10.015;
    region.span=span;
    [mapView setRegion:region];

    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" latitude:%f longitude:%f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```